# How can I get a list of player IDs on the server without starting the game?

Tags: steam

Sorry for my English.
When I launch the ARK Survival Evolved game and connect to the server, I can receive player IDs and track changes if someone comes in or out.
Below is the code that gives me this information.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "include\steam\steam_api.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "steam_api.lib")
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(!SteamAPI_Init()) {
        return 0;
    } cout << "\n";

    while(true) {
        int friendCount = SteamFriends()->GetFriendCount(0x10);
        cout << "friendCount: " << friendCount << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < friendCount; ++i) {
            CSteamID playerID = SteamFriends()->GetFriendByIndex(i, 0x10);
            long long steamID64 = playerID.ConvertToUint64();
            //...
        }
        //...
        Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function

```
SteamFriends()->GetFriendCount(0x10)
```

returns the number of players that are displayed in the overlay in the "current game".

If I terminate the game through the task manager, the connection will continue and I will continue to receive the IDs and track the changes! Therefore, the presence of a running game is optional.

How can I get a list of player IDs on the server without starting the game? I know the IP and port.

Function

```
SteamUser()->TerminateGameConnection(1438555551, 7783);
```

breaks connection with overlay (friendCount == 0). However, the inverse function

```
SteamUser()->InitiateGameConnection(pAuthBlob, cbMaxAuthBlob, k_steamIDNonSteamGS, 1438555551, 7783, true);
```

does not connect back (perhaps the third argument is incorrect).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?